# Half duplex setting switch forwarding frame collides with host forwarding frame

Tags: switch, ethernet, networking

So my question is regarding half duplex switches connected to hosts. Consider a case where a switch is connected to a host by a single link. In an event where a switch decides to forward a frame to that host, it starts to transmit the frame over the link. However, the receiving host could decide to send a frame at the same time as the switch, resulting in a collision.

My question is, since the switch is only responsible for forwarding frames to hosts, how would it ever retransmit the corrupted frame even if it manages to detect collision ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSMA/CD and half-duplex mode are mostly a thing of the past. Gigabit Ethernet and faster ports only use full-duplex mode.

> since the switch is only responsible for forwarding frames to hosts, how would it ever retransmit the corrupted frame even if it manages to detect collision ?

A switch *is* responsible for forwarding a frame, unlike with a *repeater hub* where the responsibility is that of the sending node. (A repeater doesn't buffer a frame, so it needs to propagate a collision back to the sender.)

A switch, just like an end node, simply detects the collision, backs off and retries the buffered frame after a random period. If another collision takes place the process repeats until transmission is successful.